# Potential Difference in Electromagnetic Induction

Tags: electromagnetism, potential, electromagnetic-induction

Is $\int E \cdot \text{d}s$ for a branch having non-zero current $I$ and resistance $R$ equal to $IR$ if the current is induced by varying magnetic field?

Comment: What is th emeaning $\int \mathbf{E} \cdot d\mathbf{s}$ for a branch? Is it a contour integral? or a surface intergal? what is a "branch"?

Comment: Yes. By Ohm's Law